# Parse just went AWOL

Tags: ios, parse-platform

1) I woke up this morning and my `currentUser().objectId` was different from what it has been the past 3 months. Now all of my personal data is lost and my profile is empty. My `objectId` is the same as my old one on the Parse dashboard. For some reason it's different on my device, and I've tried logging out/in repeatedly.

2) None of my queries are returning any objects. I've been using many of the same queries for months, all have worked great, but now they're not returning anything.

Is this Parse's fault? I have until April 28th to migrate my data so I shouldn't be expecting these results. Why is it going crazy?

Comment: Could it have anything to do with https://status.parse.com/incidents/4yqb0ql59vz1? When is "this morning" for you?

Comment: I hope so. I'm even querying objects with `getObjectInBackgroundWithId`, passing multiple `objectId`'s in, and still getting `[Error]: No results matched the query. (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.4)`